# How can I solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

My index default like this :

```
...
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/assets/script/script.js"></script>
    ...    
    <script src="/Content/assets/script/combined.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

My script.js like this :

```
function swiperHomepage(swiperOpt) {
    //console.log(swiperOpt)

    if ($('body').hasClass('pagemode-edit')) {
        var swiper = new Swiper(swiperOpt.className, {
            ...
        });} else {
        var swiper = new Swiper(swiperOpt.className, {
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

My combined.js like this :

```
if (!$('body').hasClass('pagemode-edit')) {
    console.log('works');
    var slidercouter = 0;
    $('.sec-homepage .swiper-slide').each(function () {
        var lengthx = $.trim($(this).find('.swiper-slide-bg').html()).length;
        if (lengthx == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
            slidercouter++;
        }
        if (slidercouter <= 1) {
            $('.swiper-pagination').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
var swiperOpt = {
    className: $('.swiper-container.swiper-homepage'),
    numberPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0
}
swiperHomepage(swiperOpt);
```

If the index run, there exist error like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Swiper.updateSize (swiper.min.js:173)
    at Swiper.update$$1 [as update] (swiper.min.js:444)
    at animateContent (script.min.js?v=1.17:55)
    at swiperHomepage (script.min.js?v=1.17:56)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (combined.js?v=0.0.20:244)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

error `HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (combined.js?v=0.0.20:244` is `swiperHomepage(swiperOpt);` in the combined.js

Seems the problem is it doesn't seem to be able to call functions between external js files

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: console.log on the data that you send to swiper, and check the documentation if you are giving it the data that it wants.

Comment: @some if I put `if (!$('body').hasClass('pagemode-edit')) {` in the form of inline style in index.html it works. but if I put it on external js (combined.js), there exists error above

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to be ready before you try to access it? (your javascript is executed directly, before the whole page has been loaded)

Comment: @some I had put it in the `$(document).ready(function () {`. But it's the same

Comment: It doesn't seem you're showing us the code where the error actually occurs. What is the `Swiper` object? I this an object you created or does it come from some library? What is the `updateSize` method? What is the original source of `swiper.min.js`? If we can't see the method where the error occurs it's much harder to see what the error is.